# Reorder a dictionary to fit a data frame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have I `dictionary` in this format:

```
d = {'Name 1': list_of_links,'Name 2': list_of_links,'Name 3': list_of_links}
```

need to put this data in a `DataFrame`, with two `columns`:

```
Names and Links
Name 1    -> Link
Name 1    -> Link
...              ...
Name 2    -> Link
Name 2    -> Link
...             ....
Name 3    -> Link
Name 3    -> Link
```

I've try this:

```
links = []
names = []

for key in d:
    names.append(key)
    links.append(d[key])
```

and then to match the length

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    names[i] =[names[i]]*len(links[i])
```

And finally copy all the values in two new lists, but it doesn't seem like a good aproach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a `dict` of two names and 10 different `links` each:

```
d = {'Name 1': ['link{}'.format(l) for l in list(range(10))], 'Name 2': ['link{}'.format(l) for l in list(range(10, 20))]}

{'Name 1': ['link0', 'link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5', 'link6', 'link7', 'link8', 'link9'], 'Name 2': ['link10', 'link11', 'link12', 'link13', 'link14', 'link15', 'link16', 'link17', 'link18', 'link19']}
```

You could create a `DataFrame` [`.from_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), [`.stack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), and clean up the [`index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['name', 'link']
```

to get:

```
      name    link
0   Name 1   link0
1   Name 1   link1
2   Name 1   link2
3   Name 1   link3
4   Name 1   link4
5   Name 1   link5
6   Name 1   link6
7   Name 1   link7
8   Name 1   link8
9   Name 1   link9
10  Name 2  link10
11  Name 2  link11
12  Name 2  link12
13  Name 2  link13
14  Name 2  link14
15  Name 2  link15
16  Name 2  link16
17  Name 2  link17
18  Name 2  link18
19  Name 2  link19
```

Comment: Thanks, could you point where is the documentation of this? some keys doesn't has values and then doesn't appear at the dataframe, in this case that is what I want but that won't be always the case.

Comment: See updated answer for docs on methods used, in general here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/. The above also works when there are different number of links per `name`. Do you mean some `names` can have no or empty `list_of_links`?

Comment: Also in this case the columns doesn't have a name, how can I add a name?

Comment: Yeah, for example 'Name 6' could have an empty list

Comment: Updated to add `columns` names. With empty lists, you could add a default: d = {k: (v if v else ['no link']) for k, v in d.items()}

Answer (score 1):

Here , you can also build the DataFrame from tuples :

```
pd.DataFrame([(i,k)  for i in d.keys() for k in d[i]],columns=['names','links'])
```